# Streaming ServerClient with Netty and Vlcj

Tags: netty, vlcj

I want to make a streaming audio/video server-client application. Here Client will request for a video/audio file to the server and client can watch the streamed files.

Now, I have heard about Netty a Network Framework very good one. So, I want to use this framework for my application.I am badly in need of any tutorial,Source Code, related documents for making RTSP/RTP server-client with netty and Vlcj.

I have looked over the google , but alas i could not find any one document which will teach me how to write the RTSP/RTP server-client for audio/video streaming...